# I need a regular expression to find text before and after a specified string

Tags: regex

So I have a query like this (ignore the fact that this is not a real query, just using to get my point across)

```
SELECT 
    [Test1].[Value]
FROM [test1] AS [testing]
JOIN test2 AS testing2 ON [stuff].[mtfID] = [otherstuff].[id]
    AND ((ESP_LOC_3].[LOCDescription] = @ParamMTF))
```

Essentially what I need to do is anywhere that '@Param' exists, I need to be able to extract out everything before it to the 'AND' and after it to the '))'. So regarding my example, I would want to match this: 'AND ((ESP_LOC_3].[LOCDescription] = @ParamMTF))'.

I have only been able to get '@ParamMTF)) with the following expression:

```
(?=@Param)(.*?)(?=\)\))..
```

Comment: If AND is always on a new line is very simple. can you confirm that's the case?

Comment: Unfortunately no, AND will not always be on a new line. It will sometimes be on the same line with the rest of the join.

Comment: The query is always in the form you are showing or it can contain other 'AND's?

Comment: Yes, the query can be longer and contain more ANDs.

Comment: So it looks like you need backreference :)

Comment: What if that AND is inside another AND? you want to match the innermost only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps if you give multiple examples of what you'd like to have matched and not matched ('expected result').

As I understand it now the basic approach seems sufficient:

`(AND.*@Param\w+\)\))`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3V13tU/1)

Comment: Cool. Note the `single line` flag in the demo which affects end-of-line matching.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write pretty complicated REGEX if you want to match the non existence of something. Your requirements can be interpreted as

> 'AND ((' followed by no 'AND' followed by '@Param' followed by '))'

As you realize, checking for the `no AND` part is very complicated using REGEX and REGEX is not the best way to do that.

We can use another REGEX that might do something similar, but not exactly the same, if we interpret it as

> 'AND ((' followed by '@Param' followed by '))'

For that, you can use the simple regex below

```
AND\s*\(\(.*?@Param.*?\)\)
.*? - matches any text in a non greedy fashion
```